# Remove charset in Content-Type header in Citrus

Tags: citrus-framework

I'm using v2.6.2 of the Citrus Framework to write automated tests for a rest end point using the http module.  Citrus is appending `charset=UTF-8` to the `Content-Type` header.  The server is responding 415 Unsupported Media due to the charset being present.

I cannot modify the rest end point.

Can I configure Citrus and the http module to not append the charset?

Comment: So, if you set the content type through the java dsl, it does not append the charset.  If you set up a client in the xml dsl as a bean then reference it in your code, it appends the charset.

I will post this as an answer in a day unless I get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was related to Citrus Http message converter always adding the default charset "UTF-8"which is set as attribute on the `citrus-http:client` component. So you need to overwrite the Content-Type explicitly in each send operation in order to not add the default charset.

Since Citrus 2.7.2 you can set the charset on the `citrus-http:client` component to an empty string. This fixes the charset appendix.

Comment: I have a system under test that automatically sends out http messages that I want to validate with a citrushttpserver, and during validation I'm seeing the same thing; how do I disable it in this case?